# No such module error trying to update Crashlytics to v3.10.3

Tags: ios, swift3, cocoapods, xcode9, crashlytics

I have updated Crashlytics to version `3.10.3` but I can't use it because I get this error when trying to import the module:

```
No such module 'Crashlytics'
```

Restoring version `3.10.2` compiles fine.

I'm integrating it with CocoaPods.

I see that in Pods/Crashlytics there are absolutely no headers for the framework.

So my question is: is it a problem with my configuration or it's a problem with Crashlytics v3.10.3

**Sample project**: https://github.com/lorenzOliveto/TestCrashlytics

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. I couldn't reproduce this. Do you see the Crashlytics framework in the "iOS" directory pods -> Crashlytics -> ios? If not, which version of Xcode and CocoaPods are you running?

Comment: Hello, I'm using Cocoapods v1.5.3 and Xcode 9.4.1. 
Yes I see the Crashlytics framework in the iOS folder, I have also a Crashlytics framework in the parent folder (directory pods -> Crashlytics).

Comment: Is your header pointing to the framework under iOS?

Comment: I'm trying to import it in swift with 'import Crashlytics'. My "Framework search paths" has this line ""${PODS_ROOT}/Crashlytics/iOS""

Comment: I uploaded a sample project here: https://github.com/lorenzOliveto/TestCrashlytics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved uninstalling all the old versions of CocoaPods, cleaning the cache folder and then reinstalling CocoaPods.

Answer (score 1):

**Did You add Crashlytics under the perticular project target ? like this --**

```
target 'App_target_1' do
  platform :ios, '9.0'
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Fabric'
  pod 'Crashlytics', '~>  3.10'
  # Pods for App_target_1
end

target 'App_target_2' do
      platform :ios, '9.0'
      use_frameworks!
      pod 'Fabric'
      pod 'Crashlytics', '~>  3.10'
end
```

Comment: No I have only one target, thats the mail app.

Comment: ok just a quick fix, it worked almost every time .... first comment out or remove the "pod 'Crashlytics', '~>  3.10" and run command - pod install ..... it will remove the pod from your project and again add "pod 'Crashlytics', '~>  3.10" and run command - pod install it will redownload and install the pod in your project ......

Comment: **** Please check your internet connection ..... make sure everything in open .... because sometime office internet firewalls block some pod downloads..

Answer (score 0):

I ended up uninstalling Crashlytics from Pods, and then re-installing it.

The tell-tale sign was the Crashlytics Folder under Pods only had support files. Once I did this, it was full of other files. My fabric folder also has the same issue